# bind and cascade dropdown list mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My view is

```
<div id="Countryy">
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, "Country")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Country", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
    </div>
    </div>

   <div id="Statess">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, "State")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("State", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="Cityy">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, "City")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("City", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
    </div>
    </div
```

MY controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Student student = db.Students.Single(s => s.ID == id);


        ViewBag.Country = new SelectList(db.Couns, "ID", "CountryName", student.Country);
        ViewBag.State = new SelectList(db.States.Where(d => d.CountryID.Equals(student.Country)), "StateID", "StateName", student.State);
        ViewBag.City = new SelectList(db.Cities.Where(x => x.StateID.Equals(student.State)), "CityID", "CityName", student.City);


        return View(student);
    }
```

> Blockquote

My question is how can i cascade the country ,state and city dropdown list.This view is generated when i want to edit the data.the saved data from db is retrived and binded to controls but when user changes the value of country dropdown than state dropdown should also be populated according to it.I have country,state,city 3 different tables in db with the required pk and fk

Comment: You should have to call ajax when country dropdown change event happens and in that you will have to fill your relevant dropdown.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan how to made a ajax call. i am newbe can you give me a example plz

Comment: find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41828/JQuery-AJAX-with-ASP-NET-MVC) article.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Solution for Country and State Cascading Dropdown in MVC using Ajax:- 
First dropdown bind by retaining view bag by controller and for second drop down we can use JavaScript/Jquery to fill value based on selected country.
Below code used on cshtml page:

```
     <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, new SelectList(Model.Country,       "Value", "Text"), "Select Contry", new { onchange = "CountryChange()" })
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
             @Html.LabelFor(m => m.State)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("state","Select State")
           </div>
```

We have used “CountryChange()” javascript function to fetch and fill data in state dropdown based on country change. Below is the JavaScript function implementation.

```
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function CountryChange () {
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/Account/GetState")';

        var ddlsource = "#Country";
        var ddltarget = "#State";
        if ($(ddlsource).val() != "") {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $.getJSON(url, { Sel_Country: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                $(ddltarget).empty();
                $("#State").append("<option  value=''>Select State</option>");
                $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                $("#State").append("<option value='" + optionData.Value + "'>" +     optionData.Text + "</option>");
                 });
             });
        }
        else {
           $("#State").empty();
            $("#State").append("<option value=''>Select State</option>");
       }
   }
 </script>
```

Here json url specified “~/Account/GetState” is method “GetState” available in “Account” controller to retrieve data and pass data in json format.

```
        public JsonResult GetState (string Sel_Country)
        {
        CountryService db = new CountryService ();
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        var vStateList = db.GetStateList(Convert.ToInt64(Sel_Country));
        result.Data = vStateList.ToList();
        result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
         return result;
        }
```